# Fill data table using access - C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, datatable

I built a connection string to access data from a database to fill a datatable.

```
connectionname = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=d:\\projects\\checking.mdb; OLE DB Services=-1"

DataTable results = new DataTable();
using (OleDbConnection thisConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionname))
{
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * from PatTestTable", thisConnection);

    thisConnection.Open();

    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

    adapter.Fill(results);
}
```

There is no error and in the debug mode, I can see the connection string being built correctly but the `results` datatable is empty. Did I miss any step?

Comment: Do you have data in PatTestTable?

Comment: Notice you can create a using-block for your command as well.

Comment: found the issue. the connection string wasn't being built properly. i can populate it now.

Comment: It is good to have a try - catch block so you can see these kind of problems.

Comment: @DDan how to do that?

Comment: Similar like in the code example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680845/try-catch-every-db-connection#4681211